# How to interpret A<B<T>>* as A<C<T>>* where B : public C<T>?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

Consider a file main.cc with the following code:

```
template<typename Commodity>
class Shop
{
public:
    Shop(){}
    ~Shop(){}
};

template<typename FuelType>
class Car
{
public:
    Car(){}
    virtual ~Car(){}
};

template<typename FuelType>
class Volkswagen : public Car<FuelType>
{
public:
    Volkswagen(){}
    ~Volkswagen(){}
};

int main()
{   
    // this is fine...
    Car<int>* myCar = new Volkswagen<int>();

    delete myCar;

    // ...but this isn't
    Shop<Car<int>>* myCarShop = new Shop<Volkswagen<int>>();

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile, I get an error:

```
cannot convert 'Shop<Volkswagen<int> >*' to 'Shop<Car<int> >*' in initialization...'
```

Now, I understand **why** I get this error. It's because `Shop<Volkswagen<T>>` in general does not have to inherit from `Shop<Car<T>>`.

**My question** is: How can I implement a structure like this? Is there a better way with classes and templates or should I, when I'm absolutely certain that `Shop<Volkswagen<T>>` always is a `Shop<Car<T>>`, attempt to explitly cast the pointer?

**Edit 1:** One solution could be to add a class

```
template<typename FuelType>
class VolkswagenShop : public Shop<Volkswagen<FuelType>>, public virtual Shop<Car<FuelType>>
{
public:
  VolkswagenShop(){}
  ~VolkswagenShop(){}
};
```

and then write

```
Shop<Car<int>>* myCarShop = new VolkswagenShop<int>();
```

This compiles, but the structure has gotten complicated to a point where I, with my very limited c++ ability, am not sure if this won't cause any problems.

So, risking being too vague, **will the above solution cause any obvious problems?**

Comment: `Shop<Volkswagen<T>>` and `Shop<Car<T>>` are distinct and unrelated types. But you can make `Shop` manage a `Car` pointer internally.

Comment: You can't in c++ `Shop<T>` and `Shop<U>` are completely separate classes even when `T` and `U` are related

Comment: I realise this is just an example, but why do `Car` and `Volkswagen` have to be templates?

Comment: @PaulSanders to mimick the structure of a much larger project where I'm having this problem

Comment: i dont completely understand your attempted solution. Would inheriting `Shop<Volkswagen<T>>` from `Shop<Car<T>>` be a solution? It sees like that is what you want

Comment: @idclev463035818 If that's possible, it'd be great. But I don't know how to do that. Can you tell me?

Comment: do all `Shop`s sell cars? Or do you have also shops for furniture? In other words, is it always `Shop< class_inherited_from_car <T>>` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 never mind, all shops sell cars.

Comment: You should attempt doing Car an pure virtual interface.

Answer (score 1):

Template instantiation is not inheritance! `foo<A>` and `foo<B>` are two distinct and unrelated types. If you want all `Shop<CARTYPE<T>>` to inherit from `Shop<Car<T>>` then you can do that.

If it is ok to change the declaration of `Shop` to take 2 template parameters (and if you are not scared of template template parameters) you can do this:

```
template<typename FuelType>
class Car
{
public:
    Car(){}
    virtual ~Car(){}
};

template<typename FuelType>
class Volkswagen : public Car<FuelType>
{
public:
    Volkswagen(){}
    ~Volkswagen(){}
};

template <template<class> class CarType,typename Commodity>
class Shop : public Shop<Car,Commodity>
{
public:
    using Car_t = CarType<Commodity>;
    Shop(){}
    virtual ~Shop(){}
};

template <typename Commodity>
class Shop<Car,Commodity> {
    virtual ~Shop(){}
};


int main()
{   
    // this is fine...
    Car<int>* myCar = new Volkswagen<int>();
    delete myCar;
    // this also
    Shop<Car,int>* myCarShop = new Shop<Volkswagen,int>();
    delete myCarShop;
    return 0;
}
```

However, template specialization is also not inheritance! You will need to repeat all methods in the general template and in the `template <typename Commodity> class Shop<Car,Commodity> {};` specialization. To avoid code duplication you could write a `ShopBase` class that is not a template and provides the interface you want to use polymorphically on all shops.

PS: Mixing compile time and runtime polymorphis is possible, but I would reconsider what you really need. Taking a look at [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) might give you some inspiration.